# How to convert object list to DF in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, jodatime

Using spark 2.4.X, one of the complex objects has a field of type Joda `DateTime`.

I want to convert this complex object to DF. Below is the sample snippet:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.joda.time.{DateTime, DateTimeZone}
case class JodaTuple(n: Int, dt: org.joda.time.DateTime)
val futureDate = new DateTime(2200, 1, 1, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.UTC)
List(JodaTuple(1, futureDate)).toDF("n", "t").show()
```

But facing exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for org.joda.time.DateTime
- field (class: "org.joda.time.DateTime", name: "dt")
- root class: "JodaTuple"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark used "java.sql.Timestamp" for "TimestampType", Joda type can be converted:

```
List((1, new java.sql.Timestamp(futureDate.getMillis))).toDF("n", "t").show(false)
```

In case of little bit complex object, RDD of objects can be created, and mapped to Spark types:

```
spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
   List(JodaTuple(1, futureDate))
 )
.map(r=>(r.n, new java.sql.Timestamp(r.t.getMillis)))
.toDF("n", "t").show(false)
```

Comment: Thanks, @pasha701. but It's a little more complex than you mentioned. Consider the tuple as a complex object which is already used across teams and don't want to change the datatype.

Comment: I won't be able to convert the object to tuple back using map() function